# How to validate a CSV file from a list of files to its corresponding category using C#?

Tags: c#

I have multiple CSV files in my directory belonging to three different categories(File A, File B & File C) with different column structures/data. I am writing a console application using SmartXLS library, which reads a new file(say File Z) and tells me which category(A/B/C) it belongs to.

I am able to read multiple files from the directory but not able to write the logic to validate files. Kindly, help me with this.

File Formats:
 File A: Usage Date, Product Name, User Id, Tokens Used.
 File B: Reason, Month, Adjustment Date, Transaction ID, Tokens Adjusted,
 Product Name, Comment Added.
 File C: Usage Date, Product Name, Product Version, User Id, Machine Name, 
 Server Name, Tokens Used, Hours Used.

Function:

```
 public void ValidateData()
        {
            int count = 0;

            Tokens = new List<Token>();

            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Projects", "*.csv");

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    SmartXLS.WorkBook WB = new WorkBook();
                    WB.readCSV(file);

                    DataTable dt = WB.ExportDataTable();
                    string dtSTR;
                    DataRow dr;

                    for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dr = dt.Rows[i];

                        try
                        {
                            dtSTR = dr[0].ToString();
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSTR)) continue;

                            var tkn = new Token();
                            tkn.Usagedate = ParseDateTime(dtSTR);
                            tkn.Product_name = dr[1].ToString();
                            tkn.Product_Version = dr[2].ToString();
                            tkn.Userid = dr[3].ToString();


                            Tokens.Add(tkn);
                            count++;

                            Console.WriteLine("Read : " + count);

                            Console.WriteLine("    Reading : " + tkn.Usagedate + "," + tkn.Product_name + "," + tkn.Product_Version + "," + tkn.Userid);

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: _with different column structures/data._ What are those different structures?

Comment: I tried attaching the pictures but for some reason its not allowing me.
Here is the structure:

File A: Usage Date, Product Name, User Id, Tokens Used

File B:  Reason, Month,  Adjustment Date, Transaction ID, Tokens Adjusted, Product Name,  Comment Added

File C: Usage Date, Product Name, Product Version, User Id, Machine Name, Server Name, Tokens Used, Hours Used.

Above are the coma separated  column headings of the three files @Sach

Comment: Please update your original post with this info.

Answer (score 1):

If these are simple .csv files and you just need to categorize them, you can skip pretty much all of that logic in the `using` block and just treat the files as simple text, which will probably prove to be more efficient.

You do not mention what the differences are in the formats, so I am left to guess.  Are there a different number of columns for each category?  If so, you can pick one of your rows, use `String.Split` to make an string array (one string per column) and then use the length of the array to determine how many columns there are.  It would look something like this:

```
public void ValidateData()
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Projects", "*.csv");

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        // get a string array with one string per row
        string[] fileRows = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        foreach (string row in fileRows)
        {
            // ignore blank lines
            if (row.Trim() != "")
            {
                char[] splitOn = new char[] {','}; // if the csv files use comma as a delimiter
                string[] columns = row.Split(splitOn); // this splits the row into one string per column

                int numberOfCols = columns.Length; // this is how many columns you have

                // use this info to determine the type of file.
                if (numberOfCols == 4)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("This is category A");
                }
                else if (numberOfCols == 5)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("This is category B");
                }
                else if (numberOfCols == 7)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("This is category C");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unexpected file type.");
                }

                break; // end the loop now - we've already done what we needed to do.
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If they have the same number of columns, but the information in the first column is different, then you could change your if statement to check something about columns[0] that would give you a clue about which type it was... for example, you say that file A has a date in the first column, so you could use `DateTime.TryParse(columns[0], out var date)` to return true if the first column contains a date, and false if it does not.  If you're more specific about the differences between the file types, it would be easier to give specific help.

EDIT: In the above example, the variable `row` represents the first row of data that is not blank.  If the first row of your CSV file contains the column titles, then just check the string to see what the column title is:

```
public void ValidateData()
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Projects", "*.csv");

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        // get a string array with one string per row
        string[] fileRows = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        foreach (string row in fileRows)
        {
            // ignore blank lines
            if (row.Trim() != "")
            {
                char[] splitOn = new char[] { ',' }; // if the csv files use comma as a delimiter
                string[] columns = row.Split(splitOn); // this splits the row into one string per column

                // the third column (columns[2]) is the first that is different for all file types.
                if (columns[2] == "User ID")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("This is file A");
                }
                else if (columns[2] == "Adjustment Date")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("This is file B");
                }
                else if (columns[2] == "Product Version")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("This is file C");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unknown file type.");
                }

                break; // end the loop now - we've already done what we needed to do.
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to post an answer after the OP updated with differences information, but you beat me to it. This is pretty much it. +1 no nice concise code.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I started before he posted the specifics, but this should get the OP pretty close to a solution based on his clarification.

Comment: Thank you @ElementalPete. Could you suggest me a way to validate the data using Column names instead of column count(no of columns)? because in the future the column count might change.

Comment: @Rck7 - see the updated answer.  This assumes that the column name actually appears in the spreadsheet on row 1... without knowing more about your project, that may not be a safe assumption.

Comment: @ElementalPete - I have tried your updated answer but for some reason its going in to else loop, printing "Unknown file type" (Though i gave correct column names).
Some info regarding the project: I download daily token usage data for products in multiple CSV files for each of the three categories.

So I am trying to write a console app which reads and writes all these files in to one table in the database so that I can automate the process to do all kind of calculations(sum/monthly/yearly and etc).

Is there a way you could suggest me using dictionaries? using colname, conindex as pairs?

Comment: I can't visualize how dictionaries would be helpful here...  If you are seeing "unknown file type", then columns[2] is not matching any of the options.  You can set a breakpoint at that part of the code and hover your mouse over "columns[2]" to see what IS in that variable, or add `Debug.WriteLine(columns[2]);` to print it for debugging.  Note that "user id" != "User ID" or "  user id   ", but "user id".ToLower().Trim() == "User ID".ToLower().Trim() == "   user id   ".ToLower().Trim().  You may need to use something like this to get the comparisons working.